# Handle Binary File Deletion in Code

Tags: c, linux

Let's assume I've the below C code which infinitely accepts input and prints it. I use gcc to compile it to a binary, say Test. I execute this binary in a terminal and then at the same time I delete this binary from another terminal.

Is there a way to handle this deletion in code and quit the binary which is on execution?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    while(1){
        // HANDLE BINARY FILE DELETION AND QUIT
        char input[50];
        scanf("%s",input);
        printf("\n%s\n",input);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't "handle" it, as programs don't usually get any notifications of being deleted.. The best you can try to do is to lock it to prevent deletion.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Thanks for clarifying. Could you please let me know how to lock and prevent deletion?

Comment: I believe the answer would be OS-specific (not that I know the exact mechanism on any :) )

Comment: The whole point is: in unix/linux you cannot delete a file. You can rm / unlink it, which removes it from the directory. The actual removal is done by the kernel **if the reference count to the file(inode) drops to zero** . Execution of a binary counts as a reference, so the actual contents will only be dropped once the process executing the file exits. (and yes: this is OS-specific; but the question is also tagged Linux)

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Linux/Unix has worked fine with this behavior since the 1970s with no particular issues.  Maybe you are used to Windows' strange fascination with brute force file locking?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to handle this deletion in code and quit the binary which is on execution?

C provides no mechanism specifically to recognize or respond to operations on the on-disk image of a program that is running, if such a thing even exists.  You could conceivably attempt to identify that file via `argv[0]` (which is not guaranteed to be successful), and periodically check it.  You might even find a third-party library or system-specific mechanism for registering to receive a signal when the binary discovered in that way is modified or deleted.  None of that is built into C, however.

Some operating systems might prevent such a deletion in the first place, or even provide the behavior you describe at the OS level.  Overall, though, what you propose is simply something that you should not expect or rely on to happen.  The on-disk image of a program is pretty much a separate thing from running processes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.